# Live Sass Compiler не создаёт компилированный и минифицированный файлы в папке СSS, хотя адрес указан

Tags: css, компиляция, sass, live

При редактировании файла main.scss создаются файлы main.css и main.css.map в той же папке, в папке css ничего не появляется. Путь к созданию прописан верно, компилятор вроде бы постоянно "смотрит", но так ничего и не происходит.

```
{
  "liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [
    {
      "format": "expanded",
      "extensionName": ".css",
      "savePath": "/css"
    },
    {
      "format": "compressed",
      "extensionName": ".min.css",
      "savePath": "/css"
    }
  ],
  "liveSassCompile.settings.excludeList": ["**/node_modules/**", ".vscode/**"],
  "liveSassCompile.settings.generateMap": true,
  "liveServer.settings.port": 1235,
  "liveSassCompile.settings.autoprefix": null
}
```

Как есть:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как должно быть:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `~/../css` попробуйте так.

Comment: всё так же без результата